# Excel sheet generated by pandas cannot open in MS Excel

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe

I generated an Excel file with pandas like this:

```
    df = pd.DataFrame(data=df_data)
    writer = pd.ExcelWriter("table.xlsx", engine='xlsxwriter')
    df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet1', startrow=1, header=False, index=False)
```

... and that executes without issues. However, when I try to open the Excel sheet with MS Excel cannot open. It says "Excel cannot open the file because the file format or file extension is not valid".

Anyone knows what I'm missing?

Comment: Have you tried *without* `pd.ExcelWriter`? The doc examples show that the first argument can be just the output path. Have you tried `df.to_excel('table.xlsx', sheet_name='Sheet1', startrow=1, header=False, index=False)` ?

Comment: Could it be because you haven't closed the file handle? [`ExcelWriter` should be used as a context manager.](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.ExcelWriter.html)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Panagiotis Kanavos, if it is done like this:

```
 df = pd.DataFrame(data=df_data)
 df.to_excel("table.xlsx", sheet_name='Sheet1', startrow=1, header=False, index=False)
```

it works. Thanks!